# Authors' copyright infringed

Tags: discussion

Can I draw attention to http://cookingqna.blogspot.com, which seems to be stealing content from this site, violating the copyright of the authors.  Similar sites have appeared in the past; see https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/is-http-englishqna-blogspot-com-violating-elu-or-your-copyright for information on what can be done about this.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Erik and David. Rumtscho has reported this to the [main thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here) for reporting people who violate Stack Exchange copyright. Someone here at Stack HQ will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing http://cookingqna.blogspot.com to the description of englishqna.blogspot.com at the link David posted, I see that there is now a tiny link in the upper right hand corner, saying "Credit: StackExchange" which links to us. Also there is a link to the profile of question and answer posters. This might be enough to satisfy the requirements of CC BY-SA, the license for our content. A more elaborate discussion of the attribution requirements by Jeff Atwood from StackOverflow is here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: I checked 4-5 different posts, cookingqna is crediting StackExchange for every post they copy, and linking back to each indivdual post.  This completely satisfies our license in my layman's eyes.  Look at CookingQNA as a cooking.stackexchange.com digest.

Comment: This was my conclusion after looking at it as well. They are attributing both the authors (profile links) and the questions ("more discussion"). IANAL, but I don't think that's offside re: CC-BY-SA.